# How to fix image banding in Android?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, rendering, render

I have tried setting dithering everywhere I can find. I also tried setting everything to ARGB_8888 and STILL there is very bad banding on my background image. My background image is 640x960 and it works fine on my physical phone that is 720x1280 but on an emulator running at 320x480 I get the bad color banding. I put my code below. If you have any suggestions please help!

```
public void onCreate(Bundle instanceBundle) {
    super.onCreate(instanceBundle);

    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    window.setFormat( PixelFormat.RGBA_8888 );

    surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(surfaceView);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.setFormat( PixelFormat.RGBA_8888 );

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();

    if(width > height) {
        setOffscreenSurface(height, width);
    } else {
        setOffscreenSurface(width, height);
    }

    surfaceView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    surfaceView.requestFocus();
    surfaceView.setOnKeyListener(this);

    background = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource( getResources(), R.drawable.background );
}

public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource( Resources res, int resId )
{
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options );

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inDither = true;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public int calculateInSampleSize( BitmapFactory.Options options )
{
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    int reqWidth = Math.round( width * vertDispRatio );
    int reqHeight = Math.round( height * horiDispRatio );

    if( height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth )
    {
        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round( (float) height / (float) reqHeight );
        final int widthRatio = Math.round( (float) width / (float) reqWidth );

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}

public void setOffscreenSurface(int width, int height) {
    if(offscreenSurface != null) offscreenSurface.recycle();
    offscreenSurface = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas(offscreenSurface);
}

Paint paint = new Paint();

public void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float x, float y)
{ 
    if(canvas != null)
    {
        int pixelX = (int)( x * getFramebufferWidth() );
        int pixelY = (int)( y * getFramebufferHeight() );
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, pixelX, pixelY, paint);
    }
}

public void run() {
    int frames = 0;
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    while(true) {
        if( state == State.Running )
        {
            if( !surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid() )
                continue;

            Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

            long currTime = System.nanoTime();
            float deltaTime = (currTime - lastTime) / 1000000000.0f;
            if( deltaTime > 0.1f )
                deltaTime = 0.1f;

            clearFramebuffer( Color.BLACK );

            drawBitmap( background, 0, 0 );

            src.left = 0;
            src.top = 0;
            src.right = offscreenSurface.getWidth() - 1;
            src.bottom = offscreenSurface.getHeight() - 1;
            dst.left = 0;
            dst.top = 0;
            dst.right = surfaceView.getWidth();
            dst.bottom = surfaceView.getHeight();
            canvas.drawBitmap(offscreenSurface, src, dst, null);

            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);                
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see anywhere in your code where your trying to set anti aliasing. You can also do that with the paint you use in your canvas. that should help and if not maybe the device you are using just sucks? :P

Edit:

I swore that you could set anti-aliasing through bitmapfactory but I guess not. You can definitely do it from paint though. You can set it by using the paint.setAntiAlias(aa) method.

Comment: I don't see an option for anti-aliasing in the BitmapFactory.Options. Do you know the variable name?

Comment: I did try the paint anti-aliasing which helped but it still looks pretty terrible :(

Comment: If you are worried about the banding on the emulator then maybe you should try on a real device if you can that is the size of the emulator. It may just be the emulator butchers the image. If you dont have access to a smaller device there are tons of testing sites that allow you to publish your app on a real device remotely and you can set up an account for free and use it to test that one time free.